# Using Excel VBA, how do I keep my original code executing after a 'thisworkbook.close' event in a 2nd workbook?

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel 2007, I have a sheet with a list of other Excel documents, all of which have their own VBA. My code opens the first workbook on the list, lets its vba run, then when it has completed, marks it as complete, and opens the next workbook in the list.

All this works fine unless I let one of the other workboks close itself with 'thisworkbook.close'. This stops the VBA running in the original workbook, as well as itself. If I comment this line out, it all works, but I would rather keep just the master workbook and one sub workbook open at one time.

Also, it is unpractical in this case to move all the VBA to the master workbook.

The code before is a highly simplified version to show the issue:

Workbook1's code:

```
Sub RunReports()

    Dim wkb1 As Workbook
    Dim wks1 As Worksheet
    Dim lngR As Long
    Dim strReport As String

    Set wkb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wks1 = wkb1.Sheets(strDay)

    For lngR = 4 To 1048576
        strReport = wks1.Cells(lngR, 1).Value
        'open the report. Its own VBA will take care of everything else
        Workbooks.Open strReport
        'mark the report as complete
        wks1.Cells(lngR, 2).Value = "done"
    Next lngR
End Sub
```

the code in the worksheets that are opened:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value = Now()
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
    ThisWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

If I comment out 'thisworkbook.close', it will open them all, update the time they were opened, and save them. If not, it does everything up to the first 'thisworkbook.close', closes the first sub workbook, and stops all VBA execution.

Does anyone have any ideas how to keep the "master" workbook's vba code running after the "sub" workbook's code has finished, when the 'sub' workbook's code contains a 'thisworkbook.close' (edited to make the question clear)

Comment: Not probably the answer you seek, but you really should consider using the "master"-workbook to handle the save and close events. Bind the opened book to a workbook object and use that to do the save and close commands. Thus if you wish some code to be executed in the "sub"-workbooks, I recommend not to use the ThisWorkbook_Open() event, but rather put the code in a module and call it from the "master"-file..

Comment: Do all of the "sub"-workbooks have the same exact code?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. I'd recommend you take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and possibly visit the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) if you're still unsure why I'm making this comment. As it stands it's not clear to me exactly what you're asking here. Right now your question states "My code doesn't do what I want, what can I do?" without explaining what you want the code to do in the first place. Why, for example, is it necessary for all the code to be in the sub workbooks? It might not be necessary at all, especially if it's the same code in each one.

Comment: The code is different in each sub workbook, and as there are several hundred of them, I can't go into that much detail. Using the master workbook to do everything would be possible (anything is possible), but would make for an unweidly tool for anyone to use.

Comment: And sorry if the question wasn't clear. I tried to simplify it for clarity's sake. I don't believe it would be practical or helpful to post what each sub workbook does. The question is: How do I get the vba to continue in the 'master workbook' after a 'sub workbook' has been opened by VBA, when the sub workbook's vba contains a 'thisworkbook.close' statement

Comment: I have got around it for the moment (and actually think I prefer this than my original idea) by opening the 'sub' workbook in a second instance of Excel. This allows the 'master' workbook's vba to keep running concurrently to the sub workbook's vba. I then have the sub workbook write a 'completed' file (blank text doc named the same as the sub workbook) and have the master workbook check every few seconds for the 'completed' file before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

Use standard COM ways of doing things. Take a reference to each workbook (not excel.application) using `GetObject(filename)`. Do what you want then don't close it in sub book, but set the reference to nothing in your master (which happens when you do `set exceldoc = nothing` or reach an `End Function/Sub`). Don't do both as that's voodoo programming.